# Problem with "retry until" when verifying SOAP response

Tags: karate

Please take a look at this piece of Karate report and then my problem description:
[Karate report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmUKX.png)

A you can see, I'm getting proper value of "progress" and "status", and the proof is that Karate prints them out as "0 SCHEDULED", so I assume I provide a valid xpath to those values, right?
The problem occurs when I run it in a retry loop, since I want to wait until  change to "FINISHED". And I'm getting the error below:
[retry condition not satisfied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eetqf.png)

Any ideas what is going on and what can I do to make it work?

Comment: sorry, I'm not going to look at screenshots: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - all the info you need to fix this is in the linked question. if still stuck, open a new question and be clear and specific. else, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Hi @PeterThomas, yes I know that putting screenshot is not the best practice, but I though it would be much more readable. But for the future I will be pasting it as a text :) BTW thank you, because I found the solution in the recommended topic. I used the karate.xmlPath function and it works. I somehow did not find this solution in Karate docs. So again, thanks!